# Syncing two datas in a function using javascript, Chart.js and using json

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm currently having a problem connecting these two functions. I want to sync the data of these two. for the data chart and the daterange.

```
      function dataChart(evt) {

    //Start of Chart of Shipments
    var dataIndex = $(evt.target).data('tab') || 
    $(evt.target.parentNode).data('tab');

     if(dataIndex === 1){
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.imports);
        window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.exports);
        window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
        window.chart.data.datasets[1].hidden = false;
        window.chart.update();
   }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

//Shipment Weight

```
    else if(dataIndex === 2){
       window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Weight';
       window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.weight);
       window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.height);
       window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Height';
       window.chart.data.datasets[1].hidden = false;
       window.chart.update();
    }
```

//Shipment Quantity Chart

```
     else if($(evt.target.parentNode).data('tab') === 3){
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Quantity';
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.quantity);
        window.chart.data.datasets[1].hidden = true;
        window.chart.update();
          }

      }
```

//End of Tab charts --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    $('.section-stats').click(dataChart);
```

//DATE RANGE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
     function dateRangePicker(evt){
       var rangeIndex = $(evt.target).data('range') || 
     $(evt.target.parentNode).data('range');

     var selected = dataChart(window.chart.data.datasets);

     console.log(selected);

      if(rangeIndex === 1){
          window.chart.data.labels = ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6', 'Day 7'];
          window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
          window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneWeek.map(t=> t[selected[1]]);
          window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
          window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = oneWeek.map(t=> t[selected[1]]);
          window.chart.update();
       }

      if(rangeIndex === 2){
         window.chart.data.labels = ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6', 'Day 7', 
                                'Day 8', 'Day 9', 'Day 10', 'Day 11', 'Day 12', 'Day 13', 'Day 14'];
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = twoWeeks.map(t=> t.imports);
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = twoWeeks.map(t=> t.exports);
         window.chart.update();
}

      if(rangeIndex === 3){
         window.chart.data.labels = ['Jan 1', 'Jan 2', 'Jan 3', 'Jan 4', 'Jan 5', 
                                'Jan 6', 'Jan 8', 'Jan 9', 'Jan 10', 'Jan 11',
                                'Jan 12', 'Jan 13', 'Jan 14', 'Jan 15', 'Jan 16',
                                'Jan 17', 'Jan 18', 'Jan 19', 'Jan 20', 'Jan 21',
                                'Jan 22', 'Jan 23', 'Jan 24', 'Jan 25', 'Jan 26',
                                'Jan 27', 'Jan 28', 'Jan 29', 'Jan 30', 'Jan 31', 
                                ];
          window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
          window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneMonth.map(t=> t.imports);
          window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
          window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = oneMonth.map(t=> t.exports);
          window.chart.update();

     }

      if(rangeIndex === 4){
         window.chart.data.labels = ['Jan 1-7', 'Jan 8-14', 'Jan 15-21', 'Jan 22-28', 'Jan 29-Feb 4', 'Feb 5-11',
                                'Feb 12-18', 'Feb 19-25', 'Feb 26 - Mar 4', 'Mar 5-11', 'Mar 12-18', 'Mar 19-25'];
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = threeMonths.map(t=> t.imports);
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = threeMonths.map(t=> t.exports);
         window.chart.update();

       }

     if(rangeIndex === 5){
         window.chart.data.labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.imports);
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = oneYear.map(t=> t.exports);
         window.chart.update();

      }

      if(rangeIndex === 6){
         window.chart.data.labels = ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018',];
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'Imports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[0].data = fiveYears.map(t=> t.imports);
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'Exports';
         window.chart.data.datasets[1].data = fiveYears.map(t=> t.exports);
         window.chart.update();

     }
  }

     $('.pre-selection').click(dateRangePicker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to my question I figured out to use window.selected outside the two function and set it with the words I want to use. (t=> t[selected[0]]).